# Typing Casting in Python Question

Tags: python, casting, pydev

Im a AS3 developer, currently learning Python

In AS3 Id quite often do this:

```
for ( var foo in fooArray ) {
   trace(FooObject(foo).name);
}
```

Typing casting the objects in the array, so that I get code hinting in my IDE

How would I do this in Python?

Comment: Does not appear to be a complete quesiton

Comment: He's new and was in the process of editing, which he has now done.  Vote-downers, please vote back to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Types are determined at runtime in Python.  Thus, there is typically less "code hinting" (I assume you mean completion, navigation, and so forth) in IDEs.  There is still some.

Related: a commonly used IDE for Python development with some hinting is [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) (or [Aptana](http://aptana.com/products/studio2)) with [pydev](http://pydev.org/).  Some [installation instructions](http://pydev.org/download.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no type casting in Python, as types are dynamic, so casting is completely pointless. Your IDE will give hints if it can figure out what type it is, which it often can't.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use logging.  Python has a default logging module (with five strict levels: debug, info, error, etc), but I prefer my own [tagalog](http://github.com/dorkitude/tagalog) (which supports *n* arbitrary tags on log messages).

With python logging module:

```
import logging

for foo in foo_list:
    logging.log(type(foo))
```

With tagalog:

```
import tagalog

for foo in foo_list:
    tagalog.log(type(foo))
```

Either of these approaches will write entries to a log.  The output location for tagalog is always a file, which is specified in the 'log_file_path' variable [here](https://github.com/dorkitude/tagalog/blob/master/tagalog.py).  The output location for Python's logging module ([docs here](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html)) depends on your configuration.

To watch a file in realtime, do this in the linux/unix/mac terminal:

```
tail -f /path/to/file
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question about type hinting in his IDE?

Comment: Sorry, not an Actionscript buff.  I've fixed my answer to include calls to type().

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful, but I think I'm not asking the right question. My IDE is PyDev, I'm accustomed to having code hinting when enumerating arrays in Flex Builder by type casting the object in side my for loop. The question is can I type cast like this within PyDev.

Comment: Alan: I've retagged your question with 'pydev', but you may wish to edit the contents to reflect that.  FYI even with pydev, there should be a log file (somewhere like `your_workspace/.metadata/.log`) to which you can write.

Comment: Don't mention it.  If this suits you, you could always accept or upvote me, since someone felt the need to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, Python deal with classes a little more intelligently

In Actionscript

```
for ( var f in itemArray ) {
   // call function in f
   FooObject(f).doSomething()
}
```

In Python

```
for FooObject in itemArray: 
    # call function
    FooObject.foo()
```